# Movable and zoom-able gridview inside container

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to insert GridView as child element inside Container. The idea is to make MS Excel like grid which is movable and zoom-able. So far I want to make GridView with fixed number columns and rows. But it seems I have a problem when I want to add Gestures as Zooming (similar to ImageView zoom). Do I need to create GridView.custom in order to make this functionality happen and handle with Gesture Listener?